# Why did I get a wrong answer solving this question?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

> a phone company orders $b$ iPhones. 
> Let $Y\sim U[0,100]$ be the number of people interested to buy an iPhone from the company. 
> The company sells an iPhone for everyone that is interested to buy one. 
> For every iPhone the company sells, it gets $3\$$  profit, and for every iPhone the company orders and doesn't sell, the company loses $1\$$. 
> Find for which $b$ the expected value of the profit is maximum.

**My Attempt:** 
Let $X$ be the amount of profit of the company. 
So I can say $X=3Y - (b-Y)$. All the sold $Y$ iPhones getting $3\$$ profit each, minus the remaining iPhones the company has ordered. And so: 
$E(X)=E(3Y-b+Y)=E(4Y)-E(b)=4*\frac{101}{2}-b$.
And here there's just $b=0$ as maximum, and the answer is $b=75.$

Comment: If $b\lt Y$, then $X=3b$ instead.

Comment: Also, why do you think $E(Y)=101/2$? The question says $Y$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $100$. (In fact it seems to say it has the *continuous* uniform distribution over the interval, so it could be noninteger. I don't know if that is intentional.)

Comment: @JukkaKohonen It is a discrete random variable, number of people cannot be noninteger, that's how we use the symbol here $U[x,y]$ discrete and $U(x,y)$ continuous.

Comment: There is a small "bug" in the question... It cannot be always true that " the company sells an iPhone to everyone that is interested in buying one", unless $b \ge 100$. The question should be rephrased.

Comment: @PierreCarre Exactly, that sentence made me know for sure that $b\ge Y$, and I thought there's some other mistake. I will try to solve with the help of Empy and Kavi Rama Murthy comments.

Comment: Given the sentence immediately before it implies they are only talking about the 0 to 100 people potentially interested in buying from the company, that seems like a needless over-reading of the problem. @PierreCarre

Comment: @Pwaol And if it is discrete in the set $\{0,1,\ldots,100\}$ why would you think $E(Y)=101/2$?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Good point I never paid attention that it depends on the first and last element in the set.

Comment: @Nij I think it's an important point... Even just thinking about the 0 - 100 people, since the decision to be taken  on $b$ is prior to the knowledge of $Y$, if that sentence is true, the company would be obliged to always by $b$.

Comment: Yes, that is the entire point of the question. Given perfect knowledge of the probabilities for every potential number of customers, how many phones should be bought to maximize expected profit? Now if you shift the probabilities, it is expected that the stock brought in should change as well. But that is the step beyond this level, otherwise the next question would be asked (what if the upper limit is variable? what if the number of customers is normally distributed? etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}\mathbb{E}X & =\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y>b\right]P\left(Y>b\right)+\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y\leq b\right]P\left(Y\leq b\right)\\
 & =\mathbb{E}\left[3b\mid Y>b\right]P\left(Y>b\right)+\mathbb{E}\left[4Y-b\mid Y\leq b\right]P\left(Y\leq b\right)\\
 & =3bP\left(Y>b\right)+\left(4\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid Y\leq b\right]-b\right)P\left(Y\leq b\right)\\
 & =3bP\left(Y>b\right)+\left(2b-b\right)P\left(Y\leq b\right)\\
 & =3bP\left(Y>b\right)+bP\left(Y\leq b\right)\\
 & =2bP\left(Y>b\right)+b\\
 & =2b\left(1-\frac{b}{100}\right)+b\\
 & =\frac{1}{100}\left(300b-2b^{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

This expression takes a maximum value $112.5$ for $b=75$.

---

**Edit**:

As MathLover commented a **mistake** has been made above.

We do not have $P\left(Y>b\right)=1-\frac{b}{100}$ but $P\left(Y>b\right)=1-P(Y\leq b)=1-\frac{b+1}{101}$

This leads to outcome $\frac{1}{101}\left(301b-2b^{2}\right)$ and a maximum for $b=\frac{301}4=75.25$ at first hand.

Of course $b$ must be an integer and (again) we get $b=75$ as final answer.

Comment: Thanks alot, could you please explain why the first equality is true? (the name of the theorem). I know that for $P(X=x)$ but don't remember for $E(X)$

Comment: By definition for rv $X$ and event $A$ we have: $\mathbb E[X\mid A]:=\frac{\mathbb E[X1_A]}{P(A)}$ leading to:$$\mathbb E[X\mid A]P(A)+\mathbb E[X\mid A^c]P(A^c)=\mathbb E[X1_A]+\mathbb E[X1_{A^c}]=\mathbb EX$$Unfortunately I don't know a name for it.

Comment: I found a name: ["law of total expectation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: While the approach is correct and the final answer is correct, there seems to be mistake in probability you have taken? There are $101$ possible values of $Y$ with probability of $P(Y = y) = \frac{1}{101}$ so the denominator cannot be $100$.

Comment: The final expression as per my calculation is $E(X) = \frac{301b - 2b^2}{101}$

Comment: @MathLover I think it should be $P(Y>b)=1-\frac{b+1}{101}$. Thank you, I will repair

Comment: @MathLover Repaired.

Comment: Yes it's all good now :) +1

Answer (score 2):

My math is very similar to the answer of drhab.

Suppose that you buy $x$ iphones.

Then, $\frac{x}{100}$ of the time you will sell some but not all, and $\frac{100-x}{100}$ you will sell all.

Of the $\frac{x}{100}$ fraction of the time, the profit is **linear** with the amount sold, as the amount sold ranges from $0$ through $x$.  Therefore, you can assume that you will sell exactly $\frac{x}{2}$ phones in this case.  This means that your profit will be

$[3 \times \frac{x}{2}] - [1 \times \frac{x}{2}] = x.$

So, your overall profit here is represented by $\frac{x}{100} \times x$.

---

Of the $\frac{100 - x}{100}$ fraction of the time, your profit will be $3 \times x$.

---

So, your overall profit will be 
$\frac{1}{100} \times [x^2 + 300x - 3x^2] = \frac{1}{100} \times [-2x^2 + 300x].$

So, you want to maximize $f(x) = 300x - 2x^2.$ 
$f'(x) = 300 - 4x$. 
$f''(x) = -4$.

So, $f'(x) = 0 \iff x = 75,$ in which case $f''(x) < 0.$

This implies that $f(x)$ is maximized at $x = 75.$